# how do i avoid a memory leak when i can't dispose of the data right away

Tags: c++

My problem is this, I have an object that I will push into a vector right after I initialize it.  The vector will be used long after the current method goes out of scope.

The code looks like this:

```
DataObject *ptrDataObj = new DataObject();
Parent::DataVector.push_back(ptrDataObj);
:
:
// end of method
```

This implementation will lead to a memory leak for sure.  However, if I use RAII instead of a pointer, the DataObject will have gone out of scope by the time DataVector will use it.  The only alternative I see may involve a copy of some sort.

I've been immersed in C# for many years now and am trying to reacquaint myself in the native world again.

Please advise..

Comment: You don't have a memory leak here. You do have a memory leak if you later remove the pointer from your DataVector but forget to delete it. So don't forget to delete it at that point.

Comment: You can have an vector of unique_ptr or shared_ptr

Answer (score 4):

Why is your vector storing objects by a pointer instead of by value?

Make your vector be one of:

- `std::vector<DataObject>`
- `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DataObject> >`.

Also, if you're using C++11, you can use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to avoid a copy.

```
std::vector<DataObject> vec;
vec.emplace_back(constructor_arg1, constructor_arg2);
```

Comment: This is a simplistic translation, the vector will actually store objects that contain a pointer to the data object I just initialized. 

Wrapper wrapObj(ptrDataObj);
Parent::DataVector.push_back(w);

This is really what I meant to illustrate.

Comment: The comment doesn't make it any more obvious to me what the limitation you're seeing is. I think you'll need to edit the question and add some additional context. (I.E, what is Parent::DataVector).

Answer (score 2):

> However, if I use RAII instead of a pointer, the DataObject will have gone out of scope by the time DataVector will use it.

Not if you use it appropriately. If you use a reference-counting smart pointer, the object will live at least as long as the vector, and will be properly disposed of.